# Analytics registering events only after app uninstall

Tags: firebase, react-native, expo, analytics, firebase-analytics

I am using react-native-firebase/analytics in order to log analytics for my application. I am using expo and even though that iOS works like a charm, on Android, I have to delete the application for the events to get logged to the Realtime view of Analytics. Is there any workaround this?

iOS shows events as intended, with the parameters and all, but in android they are shown only after the app is uninstalled from the device, whether it is a live device or an android studio emulator.

Tried:

- Triggering the events through the app

Expected:

- To get the events logged on Realtime section of analytics, like it happens when I am using iOS emulators

Answer (score 0):

Generally, events logged by your app are batched together over the period of approximately one hour and uploaded together. To help with troubleshooting, you can enable debug mode on your device, it will tell firebase to dispatch events with a minimal delay. You can then monitor them inside the DebugView window in the Firebase console (dashboard -> Analytics -> DebugView).

On Android, simply execute the following command:

adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app <package_name>

On iOS, open Xcode and go to Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme. Add the following argument to 'Arguments Passed On Launch' in the Run -> Arguments section.

-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled xcode-debug

[FIRAnaylticsDebugEnabledImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NTCIx.png)

Note that this will only ever work when running the app in Debug mode. Production builds will always use the regular event dispatching system.

Information obtained from the following post: https://hybridheroes.de/blog/2018-10-05-react-native-firebase-analytics/